# How to access native xml database (eXist-db) from codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, xquery, exist-db

For my final project I have to use native xml database processed by xquery, of course. I also want to use the codeigniter framework. The problem is I don't know how to connect to the exist database and how to manipulate the xml files with xquery under codeigniter. Please, do tell any hint. I'm struggling for so long to come up with a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a PHP library would work for you, the [eXist-db documentation](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/) links to https://github.com/CuAnnan/php-eXist-db-Client.

Comment: Thank you, that will work for me. I also found this library: http://query-exist.sourceforge.net/     .

Comment: I haven't used either, but the date on the query-exist project (2007) concerns me, since eXist-db has developed quite a bit since then (from ~1.2 then to 2.2 now).  The github project is much more recent.  You might also find eXist-db's REST interface more straightforward.  This discussion from the exist-open mailing list is relevant: http://markmail.org/message/czsnd56tqjrwcdys.  (Marking my response as "answer" would be great, if you think it is so!)

Comment: One last request: I see XQuery is only for querying; is there any library that allows me to work with XQuery Update? I need to insert nodes/atributes, modify the structure of the xml document in general. Thanks.

Comment: Thx!  As you probably guessed, many XQuery implementations have update facilities.  I'm most familiar with eXist-db's, which is documented at http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/update_ext.xml.  Works very well.  You're welcome to join the exist-open mailing list - a nice community there and a good place for questions: https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/exist-open.

Comment: I will join that nice community right away, but since you've proposed the update_ext extension, would be so kind as to tell me how should I use this extension since it doesn't work with the library found on github? Thank you.

Comment: It should work just fine with the library on GitHub.  You'd use the XQuery Update expressions in the body of your XQuery (i.e., in the sample PHP in the README.md file, it would go into the `prepareQuery` bit.  I forgot to mention XUpdate and eXist-db's REST interface as alternate methods for updating and interacting with the db.  This is a helpful thread: http://markmail.org/message/4f5qalqpj6zz2pma.

Comment: Yes, it works fine. Thank you. For those looking to use this method, don't let yourself fooled by the fact that changes don't appear in the xml file after executing a query. You have to reload it to see the results(File->Reload).